# Pymel insertInput method misses connections

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm trying to use the inserInput method of Attribute class from pymel 1.0.6 under Maya 2015. But it's not working as expected:

```
from pymel.core import *

nodeA = createNode('transform')
nodeB = createNode('transform')
nodeC = createNode('multiplyDivide')

nodeA.translateX >> nodeB.translateX

nodeB.translateX.insertInput(nodeC, 'outputX', 'input1X')
```

It should insert nodeC between nodeA and nodeB. Buit it throws an error:

> The attribute 'transform2.translateX' cannot be connected to 'multiplyDivide1.outputX'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works from the listener

Comment: Oh, OK... I've tried and It works fine in pymel _1.0.9_ in _Maya_ _2017._
Probably it is a bug in the earlier versions of pymel. Unfortunately I'm developing in _2015._. I should try to overload this method temporarily or just writing _my_ instead.